# Problems using the date command command in awk

Tags: date, awk

I am writing a section of awk code that reads a log file of this format:

```
[03/02/2020 10:01:01]   SOME DATA
[03/02/2020 10:05:25]   SOME MORE DATA
[03/02/2020 11:54:38]   AND YET SOME DATA
```

etc.

I wish to determine the epoch timestamp by combining the data in fields `$1` and `$2` and including a space between them to satisfy the input format needed by the bash `date` command.

This is the section of code I have written:

```
cmd="date -d" substr($1,2,10) substr($2,1,8) " +%s"
cmd | getline this_date
print this_date
```

At the moment, when i run the script, i get this error...

```
date: invalid date ‘03/02/202010:01:01’
date: invalid date ‘03/02/202010:05:25’
date: invalid date ‘03/02/202011:54:38’
```

etc.

So it seems to me I am nearly there but, as expected, the date command wants a space between the date and time portions.

I have tried many ways to try and code a 'space' between `substr($1,2,10) substr($2,1,8)` in the first line of code above but each time I get an error.

Can anyone advise the best approach?

Comment: Do you have or can you get GNU awk? It has built in time functions that'd make this task easier and more efficient and since you're using GNU date for `-d` I suspect you do also have GNU awk (run `awk --version` if you're not sure). Which timezone are the dates in your log file? Which timezone will you be running the tool from?

Answer (score 2):

You are lacking a space between the two `substr`s you extract; and you need to add quotes to join them into a single string.

```
cmd="date -d \"" substr($1,2,10) " " substr($2,1,8) "\" +%s"
```

If you can use single quotes instead of double, that will simplify things a bit; but Awk scripts are often passed between single quotes, so I assumed you'd prefer double quotes here.

Just to spell this out, the command being run is

```
date -d "03/02/2020 10:01:01" +%s
```

which gets turned into

```
date
-d
03/02/2020 10:01:01
+%s
```

once the shell is done parsing it. The quotes are necessary to preserve the argument to the `-d` option as a single string even though it contains a space.  As such, this is more of a shell question than an Awk question really.

Comment: I'm guessing this is Apache log format; most *sane* programs produce computer-readable time stamps in their logs.